# Nodejs returning [] instead of Json

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

DataFile

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

var DataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    create_date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
}); 
var Data = module.exports = mongoose.model('Data', DataSchema); 

//Get  
module.exports.getData = function(callback, limit){

    Data.find(callback).limit(limit); 

}
```

App

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

GrabData =require('./models/Data'); 

// Connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/StephensNode', { useMongoClient: true });
//Stored in localhost via install
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log("connection Success");
});

exports.test = function(req,res) {
  res.render('test');
}; 

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Use API Please :)'); 
}); 

app.get('/Dir/Data', function(req, res) {

    GrabData.getData(function(err, Data){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        //Chuck a error
        res.json(Data);
        console.log(Data); 
        console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);
        //Sends data as json
    }); 
}); 


app.listen(3000); 
console.log('Running on port 3000');
```

I'm having a bit of an issue, for some reason it's not returning back the JSON. The mongodb does have data in. It only has the name field at the moment. I've never encountered this issue before. The console log for the database has reported that it is connected fine. I even dumped the table and recreated without any success.

Comment: Your title says "returning [] instead of Json", but "[]" would be JSON for the empty array. What is actually being returned?

Comment: The page is just an empty array instead of the data in the table. Even then, shouldn't it at least return the date?

Comment: The first argument of `find` has to be a condition, not a callback function.

Comment: Grab data is coming from the Data.js file which is the top part

Comment: `Data.find({}).limit(limit).exec(callback); ` should work.

Comment: No luck josh i'm afraid

Comment: I don't know if it is the reason your code doesn't work, but you should define `getData` as a [static model method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html). But also, I doubt the function itself makes much sense. You want to get some random entries of your collection?

Comment: I added a complete solution as an answer. Could you give me feedback if it works for you or if anything is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

You have three issues: The way you define `getData`, the way you call `find` and forgetting to provide a limit value.

1. You should define `getData` as a [static method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html).
2. `find` takes a condition as its first argument. If you want it to match all documents, just use an empty object. The second argument could be a callback function, but then the `limit` wouldn't have any effect.
3. When calling `getData` you forgot to provide a value for `limit`. Also, it is good practice to take the callback function as your last argument.

Here's how your model code should look like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

var DataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    create_date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

DataSchema.statics.getData = function(limit, callback) {
    this.find({}).limit(limit).exec(callback);
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('Data', DataSchema);
```

And this is how you should call the function:

```
GrabData.getData(10, function(err, Data){...});
```